# No installation candidate error when trying to install python-pypdf

Tags: apt, software-installation, python

I need install `python-pypdf`. So I tried to install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pypdf
```

But I get this error:

```
E: Package 'python-pypdf' has no installation candidate
```

Why?

Comment: What's your Ubuntu release and what's the output of `apt-cache search pypdf`?

Comment: `python-pisa - PDF generator using HTML and CSS (Python module)
python-pypdf2 - Pure-Python library built as a PDF toolkit (Python 2)
python3-pypdf2 - Pure-Python library built as a PDF toolkit (Python 3)`

Comment: Again, what's your Ubuntu release? And could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from your comments, you are not using Ubuntu, but Parrot Security OS.

Below command shows where is python-pypdf in my Ubuntu 16.04

```
$ apt show python-pypdf
Package: python-pypdf
Version: 1:1.13-3
Priority: optional
Section: universe/python
```

For Ubuntu, below command can add/enable some additional repository which has community maintained free software including python-pypdf

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository universe
$ sudo apt update
```

I think you should search/ask this question in [Parrot Community](https://community.parrotsec.org/).

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about what these commands are supposed to do. Plain command sequences are rarely considered answers. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: `Error: could not find a distribution template for Parrot/JollyRoger`

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04 and 16.10 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pypdf
```

Upstream Debian repositories no longer have the python-pypdf package in the latest stable version of Debian. In Ubuntu 17.04 (and later), open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python-pypdf2 # Pure-Python library built as a PDF toolkit (Python 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply install it using `pip` or `pip3` if you're using Python3.
The command is:

```
pip install pyPdf  # use pip3 with Python3
```